# How to add additional parameters to url? - encode url

Tags: ruby

How to add additional parameters to url from a hash? For example:

```
parameters = Hash.new
parameters["special"] = '25235'
parameters["code"] = 62346234
```

> http: //127.0.0.1:8000/api/book_category/? %s parameters

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

response = HTTParty.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book_category/?")


json = JSON.parse(response.body)
puts json
```

Comment: `parametrs["special"] = '25235'` is not valid when parameters is of Array class.

Comment: HTTParty supports a `:query` parameter for `get` and `post`, which makes it trivial to add the correctly encoded parameters. See https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/rubyurl.rb so there's no need for anything more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should give you a valid URI which you can use for the json query.

```
require 'httparty'

parameters = {'special' => '512351235','code' => 6126236}
uri = URI.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book_category/').tap do |uri|
  uri.query = URI.encode_www_form parameters
end

uri.to_s
#=> "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book_category/?special=512351235&code=6126236"
```

---

The Tin Mans comment on your question is probably the better answer:

```
require 'httparty'

parameters = {'special' => '512351235','code' => 6126236}
response = HTTParty.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book_category/', :query => parameters)

json = JSON.parse(response.body)
puts json
```

Comment: If you're using `URI.encode_www_form`, then use URI completely. Parse the URL then use the `query=` method too.

Answer (score 3):

The [`Addressable::URI`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/addressable/Addressable/URI) class is an excellent replacement for the `URI` module in the standard library, and provides for just such manipulation of URI strings without having to build and escape the query string by hand.

This code demonstrates

```
require 'addressable/uri'
include Addressable

uri = URI.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book_category/')

parametrs = {}
parametrs["special"] = '25235'
parametrs["code"] = 62346234

uri.query_values = parametrs

puts uri
```

**output**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book_category/?code=62346234&special=25235
```

Comment: +1 for Addressable::URI. It's a great tool.